# Use the Cauchy product to find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I proved that the serie
$\displaystyle{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n \over 3^{n}}}$ is convergent, but I want to find the value of the sum using the Cauchy product. Any suggestion ?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $$a_n=\frac 1{3^{n}} \qquad b_n=\frac 1{3^{n}}$$
then
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^{n}}\right)\times \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^{n}}\right)=\sum_k\sum_{l=0}^k \frac 1{3^{l}}\times \frac{3^l}{3^k}$$

$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^{n}}\right)^2=\sum_k\frac 1{3^k}\times(k+1)$$
$$ \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^{n}}\right)^2=x+\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^{n}}\right)$$
Where $$x=\sum_k \frac{k}{3^k}$$
Geometric series (can't we use this particular case at least?): $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^{n}}\right)=\frac 32$$

Hence $$\frac 94=\frac 32 +x$$

Finally $$x=\frac 34$$

Comment: Perfect!! Yes we can use the Geometric serie! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the Cauchy product. It is sufficient to note that $$\sum_{n\geq0}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x},\,\left|x\right|<1
 $$ hence taking the derivative $$\sum_{n\geq0}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}
 $$ so $$\sum_{n\geq0}nx^{n}=\sum_{n\geq1}nx^{n}=\frac{x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}
 $$ hence taking $x=\frac{1}{3}
 $ we have 
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n}{3^{n}}=\color{red}{\frac{3}{4}}.$$

Comment: Yes that's perfect, but the intent of the question is to use the Cauchy product, as we don't know the first result (the power series) and the use of the derivaties :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$. 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}=\left(\sum_{n\geq 0} x^{n}\right)^{2}=\sum_{m,n\geq0}x^{m+n}=\sum_{r\geq0}(r+1)x^{r}
\end{align}
(Here we use Cauchy product.) Then we have 
\begin{align}
\sum_{r\geq0}rx^{r}=\sum_{r\geq0}(r+1)x^{r}-\sum_{r\geq0}x^{r}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}-\frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Good approach too!! But as I said, we are not supposed to use the result of the power series. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n \over 3^{n}}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n \choose n - 1}\pars{1 \over 3}^{n} =
{1 \over 3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + 1 \choose n}\pars{1 \over 3}^{n}
\\[4mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{-n - 1 -n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{1 \over 3}^{n} =
{1 \over 3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-2 \choose n}\pars{-\,{1 \over 3}}^{n}
\\[4mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\bracks{1 + \pars{-\,{1 \over 3}}}^{-2} =
\color{#f00}{3 \over 4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that uses the geometric series is to recognize that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n}{3^n}&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{3^n}\sum_{m=1}^n(1)
\end{align}$$

Now, interchanging the order of summation reveals

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n}{3^n}&=\sum_{m=1}^N \sum_{n=m}^N\frac{1}{3^n}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^N \frac{(1/3)^m-(1/3)^{N+1}}{1-1/3}\\\\
&=\frac32 \left(\frac{(1/3)-(1/3)^{N+1}}{1-1/3}-N(1/3)^{N+1}\right)\\\\
&\to \frac34\,\,\text{as}\,\,N\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark